# How to change exponential to number value (export excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

In pandas, it showed the data in order no. and order item Id column but when I export to excel they become exponential form:-

[image]

I understand that the program might be read these as string.
So, I try to fix by using .astype but it doesn't work.

```
below_0 = df[df["Remark"]<0]
below_0['Order No.'] = below_0['Order No.'].astype(int)
print(below_0)
below_0.to_excel("New.xlsx")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's an Excel problem, not Python. Inn case you want to pass it further, pandas would read it right. You should change the cell format in order to see the full number.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the [Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to strings, not ints.

```
below_0['Order No.'] = below_0['Order No.'].apply(lambda x: str(x)
below_0['Order Item Id'] = below_0['Order Item Id'].apply(lambda x: str(x)
below_0.to_excel("New.xlsx")
```

Probably more efficient to use astype.

```
below_0['Order No.'] = below_0['Order No.'].astype(str)
below_0['Order Item Id'] = below_0['Order Item Id'].astype(str)
below_0.to_excel("New.xlsx")
```